# How to check the current DeveloperName in RecordType?

Tags: apex, trigger, developername

Following the call of a Trigger, I try to retrieve the current RecordType DeveloperName to compare it to a list.

How to compare ?

Illustration :

```
trigger NameTrigger on SObject (Events) {

/*  Variable declaration    */
List< String >  ListDeveloperName   =   new List< String >();   
/*0*/   ListDeveloperName.add( 'DeveloperName_1');
/*1*/   ListDeveloperName.add( 'DeveloperName_2');
/*2*/   ListDeveloperName.add( 'DeveloperName_3');

// ************************************************
// RecordType_DeveloperName = DeveloperName current
// ************************************************

/*  Switch on the RecordType, call the associated ApexClasse    */
for(String RecordType_DeveloperName : ListDeveloperName) {  

    if( RecordType_DeveloperName == ListDeveloperName[0] || RecordType_DeveloperName == ListDeveloperName[1] ) {
        // Call Apex Classe 1
    }

    if( RecordType_DeveloperName == ListDeveloperName_RecordTypeTask[5] ) {
        // Call Apex Classe 2
    }
}
```

I do hope to understand and sorry for my English.

Thank you.

Simon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you specify an interface, you can then branch dynamically using reflection.

```
trigger recordTypeHandler on SObject (events) {
    // Define an invoking interface
    interface TypeHandler {
        void action(SObject record);
    }
    // Define the first handler type
    class Type1Handler implements TypeHandler {
        public void action(SObject record) {
            // do something here
        }
    }
    // Define the second handler type
    class Type2Handler implements TypeHandler {
        public void action(SObject record) {
            // do something else here
        }
    }
    // Map the names to the correct handler
    Map<String, Type> handlers = new Map<String, Type> {
        'RecordType1' => Type1Handler.class,
        'RecordType2' => Type2Handler.class
    };
    // Map the record type IDs to names
    Map<Id, RecordTypeInfo> recTypes = SObject.SobjectType.getDescribe().getRecordTypeInfosById();
    for(SObject record: Trigger.new) {
        // If there is a valid record type handler
        if(recTypes.get(record.RecordTypeId) != null) {
            // Create a new instance of the handler
            TypeHandler handler = (TypeHandler)handlers.get(recTypes.get(record.RecordTypeId).getName()).newInstance();
            // and invoke it
            handler.action(record);
        }
    }
}
```

You can also query for the record types instead of using `getRecordTypeInfosById()` if you desire. The general methodology will remain the same.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I understand the idea, but I can not see where is the comparison of the current object with the list to call the appropriate function

Comment: I explained again, when a user insert or update a field, for example, how in the Trigger I can recover his DeveloperName or Id, to compare.
For example, if the DeveloperName == ASIA, Call function 1,
or DeveloperName == EUR, Call function 2

Comment: That's all included in my example code. TypeHandler1 and TypeHandler2 are for function 1 and function 2, respectively. The `Map<String, Type>` holds the references to the functions dynamically. Replace 'RecordType1' with 'ASIA' and 'RecordType2' with 'EUR', and you start to get the idea.

Comment: Okay that's good. Can you explain the last part of the code, the loop 'for' !?
In your 'If', why to compare '!= Null' ?

Thank's again

Comment: That simply makes sure that there is a valid function to call for the record type that is being checked. This alleviates the need to have a function for all record types, even if they require no processing.

Comment: Hi ! 
I have a compilation error on Eclipse at line "for(Task record: Trigger.new)"
Error : Loop variable must be of type SObject
Please, explaine why

Comment: @SimonG. `SObject` is only a generic type (my code is generic!). Replace `SObject` with `Task` to make it specific to a single type of record.

Comment: yes that's what I did and this is where I get an error